# Android - Parse facebook graph request response

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I having trouble about parsing a graph request response using Facebook API.

My request is as below (where pageID is the ID of the Facebook page I need) :

```
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                accessToken,
                "/PageID/feed",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                            for(int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                                item.setId(feedObj.getString("id"));
                                item.setMessage(feedObj.getString("message"));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,message,link,full_picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
```

But, my pb is where is the comment line "// insert your code here".
I followed the tutorial on androidhive, but i'm still having trouble.

My stacktrace :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          Process: com.apps.neandril.magic, PID: 29809
          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
              at com.apps.neandril.magic.WelcomeActivity$1.onCompleted(WelcomeActivity.java:135)
              at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1368)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

And the null object reference, refer to this line :

```
JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
```

If you need more explication, feel free to tell me :).

Anyone can help me please?

Thank's a lot.

Comment: Can you give us a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
    FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
    item.setId(feedObj.getString("id"));
    item.setMessage(feedObj.getString("message"));
    feedItems.add(item);
}
```

you can get data in to `item` and all feeds are added to `feedItems` so you can use this `feedItems` like this is what you want `"// insert your code here"`